# how would I be able to get a list of files that has been worked on the longest

Tags: buffers

Instead of `recentf` which returns a list of files that have been opened, how would I create a function that records the time (active buffer) that I've spent on a given file and returns the list (to a manager like ivy)?

Comment: Alt: Using length of `buffer-undo-list`: `(declare-function undo-list-rebuild-from-tree "undo-tree")
(defvar undo-tree-mode)
(defun list-buffers-sort-undo-list ()
  (interactive)
  (cl-flet ((ul-length
      (buf)
      (let ((ul
        (with-current-buffer
     buf
   (when (bound-and-true-p undo-tree-mode)
     (undo-list-rebuild-from-tree))
   buffer-undo-list)))
        (if (listp ul)
     (length ul)
   0))))
    (display-buffer
     (list-buffers-noselect
      t
      (cl-sort (buffer-list)
        (lambda (b1 b2)
   (> (ul-length b1)
      (ul-length b2))))))))`

Comment: @Tobias that too long for a comment. Maybe re-post it as an answer?

Comment: @FelipeLema It is not an answer. It is an alternative. It does not look nice but it fits into the comment, i.e., it is not truncated in any way. Paste the code behind the period into the `*scratch*`-buffer and run `M-x eval-buffer`. Afterwards you can use `list-buffers-sort-undo-list` to list buffers sorted w.r.t. their undo-length. That is something other than the time that the buffer has been **current**.

Comment: **Buffers** are not active. One of them is **current** at one point of time. Multiple buffers can be shown in one frame through windows. One of those windows is **selected**. Things that can be active according to the elisp info manual: forms such as `condition-case`, edebug, minibuffers/minibuffer windows, keymaps, mark, regions, command loops, recursive edits, minor modes, terminals, processes, overlays, text, input methods, comments, customization settings, display tables, timers, notifications.